# Do vectorspaces always have to contain lists?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a little confused about the definition of a list.
By definition: a list of length n is an ordered collection of n elements, with a finite length

[image].

but what about f<sup>\infty</sup> (I dont know how to write the symbol of infinty=/infty), but F<sup>/infty</sup> is defined to be to set of all sequences of elements
of F
[image]

here is seems as the list have infinite lenghts.
Can someone explain me were I am wrong in my thinking.
You have my graditude in advance
(Sorry for my bad english)

Comment: If the two examples are from the same book, then the author seems to make a distinction between *lists* (which are tuples of *finite* length) and *sequences* (which are indexed by the natural numbers, an *infinite* set).

Comment: Also, please visit the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to see how to typeset math properly. The $\infty$ symbol is typed with a *backslash* like `\infty`.

Comment: This author states explicitly that, in his definition of a "list", a "list" must have a finite length. Thus, $F^\infty$ is an example of a vector space whose elements are not "lists".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Those sets of tuples (finite lists) or sequences are examples of vector spaces, but there are other vector spaces.

---

An example of a vector space that isn't containing lists would be the vector space $V$ of all functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. For example $f(x)=x^2$ is one element $f\in V$ or $\sin\in V$. These are obviously not lists. The operations on this space are defined by
$$
(a\cdot f)(x) = a\,f(x)
$$
for $a\in\mathbb R$ and $f\in V$ as well as
$$
(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)
$$
for $f,g\in V$.